# Concatenate columns if same column name in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've tried re-searching on stack over but couldn't get a solution for my problem

I want to concatenate the columns if they have the same column name:

Example:

```
input = { 'A' : [0,1,0,1,0], 'B' : [0,1,1,1,1], 'C':[1,1,1,1,0],
          'D' : [1,1,0,0,0], 'E' : [1,0,1,0,1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(input)
df.columns = ['A','B','C','C','B']

   A  B  C  C  B
0  0  0  1  1  1
1  1  1  1  1  0
2  0  1  1  0  1
3  1  1  1  0  0
4  0  1  0  0  1
```

Desired output:

```
   A    B    C
0  0  0;1  1;1
1  1  1;0  1;1
2  0  1;1  1;0
3  1  1;0  1;0
4  0  1;1  0;0
```

Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can grouping by columns names and for duplicates get DataFrame, so is used `apply` with `join` for join per rows:

```
DF = DF.astype(str).groupby(DF.columns, axis=1).agg(lambda x: x.apply(';'.join, 1))
```

Or:

```
DF = DF.astype(str).groupby(DF.columns, axis=1).agg(lambda x: [';'.join(y) for y in x.to_numpy()])
```

---

```
print (DF)
   A    B    C
0  0  0;1  1;1
1  1  1;0  1;1
2  0  1;1  1;0
3  1  1;0  1;0
4  0  1;1  0;0
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this code:

```
def function(x):
    return x.apply(';'.join, 1)


DF = DF.astype(str).groupby(DF.columns, axis=1).agg(function)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [transpose](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html#pandas.DataFrame.transpose), groupby, join strings and transpose back:

```
df.T.astype('str').groupby(level=0).agg(';'.join).T
```

Output:

```
   A    B    C
0  0  0;1  1;1
1  1  1;0  1;1
2  0  1;1  1;0
3  1  1;0  1;0
4  0  1;1  0;0
```