# Combine two columns with same name pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, merge, concatenation

I have a list from an API response:

```
list = [[[['3200', 'house_number'],['northline ave', 'road'],['ste 360', 'unit'],['greensboro', 'city'],['27408', 'postcode'],['7611', 'city'],['nc', 'state'],['us', 'country']]]]
```

[image]

As you can see I have column road twice, I want to combine two road columns into one. Actually I want to write a code for, suppose if any column is repaeating any number of times I want to combine and create a new column with same column name like below:

[image]

It doesn't matter wheater the road column is reapeating or city column is repeating. Irrespective of column names code should concat or combine or merge two strings with a space delimited.

Thanks again for helping me to do this project. I appreciaate each and everryone who read this question

Regards,

Comment: do noi include images. include data in text format

Comment: Hope that helps@onyambu

Comment: @onyambu I have given list but please consider it as a dataframe

Comment: How can I consider the list as a DataFrame? you can simply paste the results of `your_data_frame.to_dict()` in your question

Comment: @onyambu df = pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame(eval(str(data))).T[0].tolist()).set_index(1).T
 ok

Comment: @onyambu Thnaks

Comment: You posted the code instead of the data. post the results of `df.to_dict()` where `df` is your data.frame

Comment: @onpambu df is coming from API response

Comment: So do you have a dataframe or a list?

Comment: {'house_number': {0: '400'},
 'road': {0: 'garden city plz'},
 'unit': {0: 'ste 510'},
 'city': {0: 'garden city'},
 'state': {0: 'ny'},
 'country': {0: 'us'}}

Comment: hope that hepls now

Comment: @onpambu pls add another key called road or city I dont have in this reposne

Comment: ```DF = DF.astype(str).groupby(DF.columns, axis=1).agg(lambda x: x.apply(' '.join, 1))
```
Does this help you ? from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65823592/concatenate-columns-if-same-column-name-in-a-dataframe

Comment: There are no duplicates in that one. So tough to tell

Comment: The answer given by @JeanleChevalier works

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate columns if same column name in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65823592/concatenate-columns-if-same-column-name-in-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
df.T.reset_index().groupby('index').agg(','.join).T

index             city country house_number  ...           road state     unit
0      greensboro,7611      us         3200  ...  northline ave    nc  ste
```